# what does "on the bins with" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, british-english

> Barry comes to clinic with Gerald, who does not read or write, but
> Barry was ***on the bins*** with Gerald for years, and he tells me that he
> and the rest of the team look out for Gerald and always will, so one
> or the other of them will bring him to clinic as long as he needs to
> come, to which declaration Gerald does not reply, being overcome, but
> bangs his fist on his knee and wipes his eye with the back of his
> hand.

This is Lucy Pollock's [The Book About Getting Older](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=0LHSDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT221&lpg=PT221&dq=%22Barry%20was%20on%20the%20bins%22&source=bl&ots=TDLTieN8A7&sig=ACfU3U2UdWtUUal7ZaTlQ_B8FBlwOG38qQ&hl=ko&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjt4uOMjqTyAhULG4gKHfYOAc4Q6AF6BAgCEAM#v=onepage&q=%22Barry%20was%20on%20the%20bins%22&f=false).

I tried to find an idiom 'on the bins with' but couldn't find any. Is it a kind of informal term for something? If so, what does it mean?

Comment: Barry and Gerald worked for a trash bin emptying service.

Comment: Barry worked as a dustbin / garbage collector with Gerald

Comment: 'Worked on the bins', 'worked on the trains/railways', 'worked on the roads' are idiomatic, at least in the UK, to show what sort of work one did. 'On' is a less opaque metaphor with 'roads' and 'trains'. The verb may be switched with some of these: 'He was on the bins/railways for over 30 years'. // Note that 'work on' = _strive to bring to [a successful] completion_ is not involved here (He worked on his essay / his abs / his boss's image).

Comment: There are several prepositions used for different types of employment in the UK. The main ones being 'at', 'in', 'on' and 'down'. Apart from 'down' which is very specific to mines and sewers the choice of preposition seems to be determined by the degree of enclosure involved. For instance I spent fourteen years working _on_ a steelworks (many, but not all, steelworkers work in the open). However I specifically worked _in_ rolling mills which are large buildings. I later worked _at_ the local council which is only partly enclosed but I worked _in_ the main office block.